# docker nodejs: no ports attached to container

Tags: node.js, docker

I've created a nodeJS docker image to test my nodeJS server. My (simple) docker file looks like this:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

I deployed this image to the google cloud container registry, and I started a new VM with the docker image attached. After a few minutes, the VM is working and I can SSH into the VM.
`docker container ls` gives me all containers running, and I see my container is running. `docker logs [containerID]` gives me the output logs. I see "server running" and "mongo connected" which means my nodeJS server is running.

The problem is: it seems that there are no ports attached to this container. When I do `docker ps`, there are not ports listed under PORTS for my image, so I cannot reach my nodeJS server from the internet.

I've checked allow HTTP/HTTPS access. What am I missing out?

**Edit:** I already found the solution myself. VMs with containers use the host network mode, and container ports have a one-to-one mapping with VM ports. The solution was to open up port 5000 in the firewall.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers#publishing_container_ports

Comment: Which commands you use to deploy the container? Do you use -P or -p to publish the exposed ports?

Comment: Can you post the log of the command docker ps and the commad that you use to run the container?